# Android save audio file and show in media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am able to download audio files into sd card from internet, but the downloaded audio files are not show in the default media player of the device. What am I supposed to do so that it gets listed in the default media player too

Comment: Will it appear when you reboot your device?

Comment: try to save your audio file where your all media files are saved

Comment: I feel that the `MetadataRetriever` might be failing to extract the `metadata` from your downloaded files. Please check if you getting any errors from `MetadataRetriever` or one of the related modules.